# NextJS cant resolve 'dns'

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

Hello I have a problem with NextJS. I get an error 'can`t resolve DNS' when I use getStaticProps and working with MongoDb. Why it happens? Error occurs only when I have MongoDB code. Also code works in NextPages but not in react components

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(
    "mongodb+srv://maciejtest:password0.vv1w4.mongodb.net/stockystocks?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
  );

  const db = client.db();

  const detailedAssetsCollection = db.collection("detailedAssets");
  const detailedAssets = await detailedAssetsCollection.find({}).toArray();

  console.log(detailedAssets);
  return {
    props: {
      assets: detailedAssets,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: I believe it's throwing an error because you're importing a server-side only library into your client-side component. Instead, you should create a `lib` or `util` folder (outside of `page`) and import a connect utility function. See the official Nextjs [with-mogodb](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb) example.

Comment: _"code works in NextPages but not in react components"_ - `getStaticProps` only works in page components, it doesn't run in regular components. That would explain the error since the imports for the server-side code aren't being used, so Next.js also includes them in the client bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I have been dreaded with this kind of a DNS issue from Atlas being on *some* wifis and had to fix that with VPN.

It may be the case for you as well. Try to test on another network if you have such, i.e. a mobile hotspot.